# Get Header's OOXML

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am unable to get the OOXML of a Header. According to the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/section) `getHeader`" method will return `Body` type. The [`Body`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body) has a method to get OOXML. But it looks like it is not returning the OOXML. Maybe I am missing something?

Here's my code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
    var mySections = context.document.sections;

    // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
    context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {

        // header
        var headerBody = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");

        // header OOXML
        //// NOT GETTING OOXML HERE
        var headerOOXML = headerBody.getOoxml();

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {

            // modify header 
            var headerOOXMLValue = ModifyHeaderMethod(headerOOXML.value);

            headerBody.clear();
            headerBody.insertOoxml(headerOOXMLValue, 'Start');


            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                callBackFunc({
                    isError: false
                });
            });

        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "art" of Office.js is to minimize the number of "syncs" you do. I know that is kind of an unnecessary burden, but that's how it is.

With that in mind, In this case you only need ONE sync.
this code works (assuming that you have only one section in the doc).
btw you can try it in script lab with this [yaml](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/d97fad310e27a265f2ac6a76d74c815e).

if this does not work, please indicate if this is Word for Windows (and what build) or Online, or Mac... thanks!

```js
async function run() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        let myOOXML = context.document.sections.getFirst()
            .getHeader("primary").getOoxml();

        await context.sync();
        console.log(myOOXML.value);

    });
}
```

Comment: I am using office API 1.1 and that throws an exception on getFirst method. Between you used "await" , is it something latest office API has or some other API ?

Comment: that's most probably because you have a SKU that does not support 1.2 (probably MSI). if that's the case you need to traverse each section and get the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of extra code here but the gist of your problem is that `headerOOXML` won't be populated until you `sync()`:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    var header = context.document.sections // Grabv 
        .getFirst() // Get the first section
        .getHeader("primary"); // Get the header

    var ooxml = header.getOoxml();

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(ooxml.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between this code and my code ? In my code, I am also reading the value after the sync. Anyway, I tried your code and it doesn't work as well. Have you tried this ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Are you sure there is a primary header in the first document section?

Comment: Imran: what you are missing in your code is the .value. in the line after var headerOOXML = headerBody.getOoxml();  headerOOXML.value will contain the OOXML you need. That's the main  difference between your code and Marc's. Also minimize the number of syncs, check my answer below.

Comment: you can only call [ooxmlObject].value after the sync and that's what Marc is doing as well.